# Protecting Kafka Cluster against remote access thru shell

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a Kafka cluster and would like to restrict access for the Non Java clients. Meaning, I can let clients connect to my kafka cluster thru SASL_SSL using the Java clients or Python client. But, I dont like them to access my cluster using the shell scripts available under /bin. I know, even the shell scripts are calling the scala library behind the scene. Is there any kafka config to restrict this?

Thanks